# DOMPDF Doesn't support arabic characters

Tags: php

Can Any one help me please,

I'm using DOMPDF and it's working good but not with the Arabic characters. It shows these (???)

I tried using :
     `<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />`
in the head tag , also :
    `<style type="text/css">`
       `html,body{`
        `font-family: 'tahoma' ;`
    `}`
    `</style>`

but it's not working. Please help me with this 
Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: How are the Arabic characters being produced?

Comment: I get them from the Database, Then display them in HTML page then use 
 `$dompdf->load_html($html);`
    ` $dompdf->render();`

Comment: How is the d/b connection set up?  Have you confirmed that you *can* display Arabic characters in the database with any other tool?

Comment: No I didn't confirm displaying Arabic letters but I think the problem is with the DOMPDF itself. Because I displayed Arabic chars in the php pages and it worked correctly. But with PDF it's not showing

Answer (score 10):

Use below style in your html

```
<style> 
 * { font-family: DejaVu Sans, sans-serif; }
</style>
```

Comment: Yep I am almost sure this will work.Had the same problem with Lithuanian characters and this was a solution. can you explain: I thought that font may be a problem, so I changed it to arial because arial has lithuanian chars in website, ms word, etc. But in this way only DajaVu font worked. Could you explain, why?

Answer (score 1):

`dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php`

```
def("DOMPDF_DEFAULT_FONT", "sarif");
```

Replace:-

```
def("DOMPDF_DEFAULT_FONT", "dejavu sans");
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to add a font to dompdf you do not need to go through all the steps as described in there wiki. I had the same problem and all I did was download the font .ttf file, then add the following css to my html:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Arial;
    src: url(template/fonts/Arial Regular.ttf);
}
body {
    background: #FFF;
    font-family: Arial;
}
```

Since we've added the font-face in our style, dompdf will grab the ttf file and display the font.

---

Another method is upload the .ttf and .afm font files (Ex: arial-regular.ttf, arial-regular.afm) to "lib/fonts/" then update the file named "dompdf_font_family_cache.dist.php" in "lib/fonts/" by adding the following code:

```
'arial' => 
  array (
    'normal' => DOMPDF_FONT_DIR . 'arial-regular',
    'bold' => DOMPDF_FONT_DIR . 'arial-regular',
    'italic' => DOMPDF_FONT_DIR . 'arial-regular',
    'bold_italic' => DOMPDF_FONT_DIR . 'arial-regular',
  ),
```

This way when you use the arial font on you html page, it will automatically load arial-regular.ttf & arial-regular.afm and display the font correctly.

---

If you have the .ttf file and not the .afm file you can convert .ttf to .afm using this online tool http://everythingfonts.com/ttf-to-afm

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by the answer by @Meldin Xavier, you can put whatever font you'd like for your document and make the font for Arabic parts "DejaVu Sans". I had to use it since I had both Arabic and English and I wanted the English parts to have different font.

Answer (score -1):

See the quick guide to turning on unicode support for DOMPDF: https://code.google.com/p/dompdf/wiki/CPDFUnicode

> For DOMPDF to handle your characters correctly you must enable Unicode support in your configuration. Edit dompdf_config.inc.php or dompdf_config.custom.inc.php so that DOMPDF_UNICODE_ENABLED is true. Without enabling this setting your text will be re-encoded to Windows ANSI when inserted into the PDF and any characters that fall outside this encoding will be converted to question marks.

Comment: Thank You for answering Sir, 
I downloaded dompdf_0-6-0_beta3.tar.gz , made sure that DOMPDF_UNICODE_ENABLED is true and created a compatible HTML document

There is this step that I don't understand very well :Load a font supporting your characters into DOMPDF. :(